# Calculating the side of a square inscribed in another square

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, area

I've recently been working on this problem:

[image]

which asks to find the side of the inscribed square in function of x.

First, I'm establishing that the side of the "larger" square is S=10cm

$$S=x+y; $$$$10=x+y; $$$$y=10-x $$

The side of the inscribed triangle will be called 'z'. The Pythagorean theorem states that $$c^2=a^2+b^2 $$$$ z^2=x^2+y^2$$$$z^2=10^2$$$$z=10cm$$

Can the side of the inscribed square be as large as the side of the exterior square?

Furthermore, I'm asked to calculate the shaded area or the four triangles.
$$A_{shaded}=\frac{4(xy)}{2}$$

Considering the fact that the area of the larger square is equal to the area of the inscribed square and the four triangles,
$$A_{square}=S^2=10^2=100cm$$
$$A_{inscribed- square}=z^2=10^2=100cm$$
$$(x+y)^2=\frac{4(xy)}{2}+z^2$$$$10^2=2(xy)+10^2$$$$0=2xy$$

I get an answer that doesn't make sense.

I'm very sorry if my English isn't good! Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you write "triangle", do you mean "square"?  And, if so, why would you need to "establish" the sidelength of the outer square?  It is given to you in the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that! I just edited it to square, what I was trying to say. I was trying to establish a connection so that it could be transformed into a mathematical expression.

Comment: What you write seems quite confused.  All you have to do is to invoke the Pythagorean Theorem in the usual way.  There is no need to compute any areas.

Comment: One side of the inner square is the hypotenuse of a right triangle.  One leg of that right triangle has length $x$ (we are told).  What is the length of the other leg?

Comment: Wouldn't it be y=10-x?

Comment: If $x+y=10$ it does not follow that $x^2+y^2=10^2$

Comment: Where you write, $z^2 = 10^2$, you have incorrectly squared $y$ and added $x^2$.  $y^2 = (10-x)(10-x) = 100 - 20x + x^2$.

Comment: @VruMises  Right.  So, now we have a right triangle with legs $x, 10-x$.  What's the hypotenuse?

Comment: Is it $z^2=(10-x)^2+x^2$?

Comment: Well, so the hypotenuse is the square root, $z$. Yes.  And, given the legs of the right triangle, what is the area?

Comment: $A_t=\frac{(x)(10-x)}{2}$

Comment: Good.  That's all you need!  Not complicated.  Note that you really can't say more.  That is, you can't actually solve for $x$ unless you are given more information.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From Pythagoras, the side length of the inscribed square is

$ c = \sqrt{ x^2 + (10 - x)^2 } = \sqrt{ 2 x^2 - 20 x + 100 }.$

For example, if $ x = 2 $ then

$ c = \sqrt{ 8 - 40 + 100 } = \sqrt{68} \approx 8.246 .$